# One line if/else in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some logic that switches(with and else/if) true/false with on/off but I would like to make is more condensed and not use a switch statement.  Ideally the if/else would be converted into something that is one short line. Thank you!!!

```
var properties = {};
var IsItMuted = scope.slideshow.isMuted();
if (IsItMuted === true) {
    properties['Value'] = 'On';
} else {
    properties['Value'] = 'Off';
}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You want a ternary operator:

```
properties['Value'] = (IsItMuted === true) ? 'On' : 'Off';
```

The `? :` is called a ternary operator and acts just like an `if`/`else` when used in an expression.

Comment: this is what i wanted

Answer (score 20):

You can likely replace your `if`/`else` logic with the following to give you a "one-liner"

```
properties['Value'] = scope.slideshow.isMuted() ? 'On' : 'Off';
```

see [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for more info

Answer (score 9):

```
var properties = {"Value":scope.slideshow.isMuted() && "on" || "off"}
```

Answer (score 7):

Combine all into one line.

You don't need to create empty object, it can have properties and if brevity is what you want don't need the `isItMuted` either

```
var properties = {Value : scope.slideshow.isMuted() ? 'On' : 'Off'};
```